# ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx() Returns Error Code 5

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I want to get the status of a checkbox in a window.

So I used `SendMessage(hwnd, BM_GETCHECK, NULL, NULL)`, but it always returns 0. To know why, I used GetLastError() and it returned 5.

In [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage), it says that "When a message is blocked by UIPI the last error, retrieved with GetLastError, is set to 5 (access denied)."

So, after some research I used `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(hwnd, BM_GETCHECK, MSGFLT_ALLOW, 0)` to bypass the privilege issues.

But `ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx()` also gives error code 5 and returns false.

However, when I use `ChangeWindowMessageFilter()` it returns true and gives the error code 0. But still `SendMessage(hwnd, BM_GETCHECK, NULL, NULL)` gives error code 5.

Approach 1

```
status = ChangeWindowMessageFilterEx(hwnd, BM_GETCHECK, MSGFLT_ALLOW, 0); //returns false
error = ::GetLastError(); // gives error code 5
chk_state = SendMessage(hwnd, BM_GETCHECK, NULL, NULL);
```

Approach 2

```
status = ChangeWindowMessageFilter(BM_GETCHECK, MSGFLT_ADD); //returns true
error = ::GetLastError() // gives error code 0
chk_state = SendMessage(hwnd, BM_GETCHECK, NULL, NULL);
error = ::GetLastError(); // gives error code 5
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `ChangeWindowMessageFilter` is called by the **target** process to allow lower-privileged apps to send messages to it. It wouldn't be a great security mechanism if any process could change another app's filter would it?

Comment: Try running your code with administrator privileges.

Comment: Also, how are able the HWND id of the child window control in order to send a message to it in the first place?  EnumChildWindows?

Comment: @JonathanPotter I'm new to this. So pardon me if I'm wrong. If I can't call ChangeWindowMessageFilter, then there is no way to change the privilege from my program is it? When I checked my process it runs with medium integrity. But I could not find the integrity of the window to which my program trying to send message. Also, I'm confused how to call ChangeWindowMessageFilter from that window's process. Am I lost somewhere?

Comment: If your low privilege process could simply disable UIPI from high privilege processes by calling a function then UIPI would be pointless. You need to ask the author of the target process to change their code to let you in. Unlikely that they will. So, run your process with admin rights.

Comment: @GowthamM "*If I can't call ChangeWindowMessageFilter, then there is no way to change the privilege from my program is it?*" - correct. "*When I checked my process it runs with medium integrity. But I could not find the integrity of the window to which my program trying to send message.*" - it must be running in a high integrity process, or else UIPI would not be blocking your message to it. "*Also, I'm confused how to call ChangeWindowMessageFilter from that window's process.*" - you can't, since it is not your process.

Comment: @GowthamM Try [Inspect.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/inspect-objects) tool to see if it can get the status of the checkbox in target window. Why do you need this information of a third-party application programmatically?

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I got the status of check box in inspect.exe. But how to retrieve that status from inspect.exe. Also, the checkbox status is displayed only after mouse over on that check box. It's interesting and I'm digging more information on inspect.exe. If you could provide any source on how to retrieve the check box status through inspect.exe it would be helpful. And I'm not working on any third party application. I'm trying to get the check box status of narrator window in control panel(```Control Panel\Ease of Access\Ease of Access Center\Start Narrator```)

Comment: @GowthamM No source code found. You may want to learn [UI Automation technique](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: @RitaHan-MSFT I have retrieved the check box status using inspect.exe(UIAutomation). Thanks for the suggesting inspect.exe. I don't need windows handle anymore. I don't have to worry about privileges anymore. But the only problem now is the check box status is retrieved only after mouse over on that element. I'm trying to find a solution for that. Anyway if you could shed any light on this that would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Finally found an alternate way to get the check box status. The inspect.exe was the savior. Thanks to @Rita Han - MSFT for suggesting inspect.exe. As changing privilege/access or bypassing UIPI restrictions are little complicated, we decided to go with UIAutomation. We retrieved all the data in the settings window using UIAutomation!

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to get the status of checkbox for the this scenario.

1. Run your program with same or high integrity level than the target program, for example run the program in the elevated mode maybe helpful since most of program is running under high integrity. You can also specify the level in the manifest like below(refer [/MANIFESTUAC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/manifestuac-embeds-uac-information-in-manifest?view=vs-2019))

   /MANIFESTUAC:level=_level
2. Bypass UIPI restrictions on SendMessage across privilege levels is available for UI automation programs using a special security attribute in the program’s application manifest, known as UIAccess.The following is an example of an application manifest entry for a UIAccess program.

   `<trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3"> 
         <security> 
           <requestedPrivileges> 
           <requestedExecutionLevel 
             level="asInvoker" 
             UIAccess="true" /> 
           </requestedPrivileges> 
         </security> 
     </trustInfo>`

*By specifying **UIAccess=”true”** in the requestedPrivileges attribute, the application is stating a requirement to bypass UIPI restrictions on sending window messages across privilege levels. Windows Vista implements the following policy checks before starting an application with UIAccess privilege.*

- *The application must have a digital signature that can be verified
  using a digital certificate that chains up to a trusted root in the
  local machine Trusted Root Certification Authorities certificate
  store.*
- *The application must be installed in a local folder application
  directory that is writeable only by administrators, such as the
  Program Files directory. The allowed directories for UI automation
  applications are:*

  - *%ProgramFiles% and its subdirectories.*
  - *%WinDir% and its subdirectories, except a few subdirectories that are excluded because standard users have write access.*

Please refer the docs about about details:

[Mandatory Integrity Control](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/mandatory-integrity-control)

> But the only problem now is the check box status is retrieved only after mouse over on that element. I'm trying to find a solution for that. Anyway if you could shed any light on this that would be great.

Instead of get the element after mouse over, we can get the element by windows handler. Here is the code to get state of checkbox for your reference:

```
CoInitialize(NULL);

IUIAutomation * UIAutomation;
InitializeUIAutomation(&UIAutomation);

IUIAutomationElement *targetIUIAutomationElement;

UIAutomation->ElementFromHandle((UIA_HWND)0x513F8,&targetIUIAutomationElement);

VARIANT checkboxState;
targetIUIAutomationElement->GetCurrentPropertyValue(UIA_ToggleToggleStatePropertyId,&checkboxState);
if(checkboxState.lVal== ToggleState_Off)
    std::cout << "The check box is not checked...\n";
else if(checkboxState.lVal == ToggleState_On)
    std::cout << "The check box is checked...\n";
else
    std::cout << "The checkbox is in indeterminate...\n";
```

Comment: The client doesn't want us to change the access/privilege. So we found a different way to get the check box status. Anyway thanks a lot for the efforts! Much appreciated.

Comment: @GowthamM You can share the solution/workaround here so that other communities who have the same issue also can benefit from this post. By the way, if the customer doesn't want to change the access/privilege, you can also choose the option 2 to by-pass the UIPI restrictions.

Answer (score -3):

If you just want to interrogate the state of a checkbox, instead of using a SendMessage, you could just inspect the accessibilitiy tree.  That is, use the same APIs that a screen reader would use.

Start with [AccessibleObjectFromWindow and friends](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winauto/client-functions).

Comment: That's also going to be subject to UIPI surely

Comment: Although technically correct, this answer doesn't do anything to try to address the question that was actually asked